# How to display "live" code from text file (running down matrix style)?

Tags: text, live

I would like to ask how I can display code (text file) that "runs down" visually, so it looks like each line of code is being written in that moment.

I need it for my artschool graduation work, I want to display "live" code on a screen.

Is there a program or an automated way to do that, so I don't have to record myself writing a thousand lines of code? Thanks!!

It should look like this:[shutterstock.com/video/clip-5586110-...](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-5586110-stock-footage-c-programming-code-running-down-a-computer-screen-terminal.html)

Comment: http://hackertyper.com/ - just mash random keys at whatever rate you need code to appear

Comment: Thanks for the link! But this doesn't work, because I can't "access" the keyboard, as the computer will be part of an installation with the code running for more than 10 hours.

Also I need a specific type of code, one that would fit to an AI.

So I need something that runs by itself, you know?